# How to set custom Marker on Google maps in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, marker

I want to set custom Markers with an AssetImage as the Marker icon on the Google Map. I already made a marker but only as a default BitmapDescriptor. How can i provide an AssetImage as the Icon for the Marker?

This is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class GMapPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const GMapPage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  static CameraPosition initialCameraPosition = const CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(
      50.07826619317443,
      8.239772862793647,
    ),
    zoom: 17,
  );

  @override
  State<GMapPage> createState() => _GMapPageState();
}

class _GMapPageState extends State<GMapPage> {
  late GoogleMapController _controller;
  final Set<Marker> _markers = {};

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _controller = controller;
    _markers.add(
      const Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId("id-1"),
        position: LatLng(
          50.07826619317443,
          8.239772862793647,
        ),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        initialCameraPosition: GMapPage.initialCameraPosition,
        markers: _markers,
        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a function to set icons from assets.

```
void setCustomIcons(BuildContext context) async {
    customIcon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
          ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.0),
          'assets/images/custome_icon.png'
        );
   }
```

you can try

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class GMapPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const GMapPage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  static CameraPosition initialCameraPosition = const CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(
      50.07826619317443,
      8.239772862793647,
    ),
    zoom: 17,
  );

  @override
  State<GMapPage> createState() => _GMapPageState();
}

class _GMapPageState extends State<GMapPage> {
  late GoogleMapController _controller;
  final Set<Marker> _markers = {};

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _controller = controller;
    _markers.add(
      const Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId("id-1"),
        position: LatLng(
          50.07826619317443,
          8.239772862793647,
        ),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
      ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.0),
      'assets/images/custome_icon.png'
    ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        initialCameraPosition: GMapPage.initialCameraPosition,
        markers: _markers,
        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage is async.

Comment: @syonip rather just saying this doesn't compile you could present what errors are you getting in the logs. Please Make sure you have added the image in the project which you want to use and make sure you have all the necessary imports in the file.

Comment: @sanchitArora I think they presented the error they are facing when they said "BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage is async"